# How to run command ''git rev-parse $REVISION' in nodejs

Tags: node.js, git

> const execSync = require('child_process').execSync execSync('git rev-parse $REVISION:./index.js')

Error info:

```
fatal: Invalid object name '$REVISION'. child_process.js:660
   throw err;
     ^
Error: Command failed: git rev-parse $REVISION:./index.js fatal:
Invalid object name '$REVISION'.
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Use the `{}` button in the toolbar of the question editor to format the code nicely (or write them between two lines that contain only `\`\`\``).

Answer (score -1):

```
const hash = execSync('git rev-parse --short $REVISION:./index.js', {
  cwd: __dirname,
  shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe',
})
```